# problems in read modify and write csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

The program does what I want with system.out.println , but I don't get the result that comes out with the previous statement being able to print to a csv file. With FileWriter I can't print the file.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      
      // archivo inicial "prueba1.csv" - linea-  7852500397148583,705034500050,45871,M501,20301231,,sonter,,,
         
     // archivo resultado 111.CSV --     7852 5003 9714 8583;705034500050;31/12/2030
   String SEPARATOR=",";
   String QUOTE="\"";

   BufferedReader br = null;
   FileWriter flwriter = null;
   try {    
        
         br =new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\java orig\\csv1\\prueba1.csv"));
         String line = br.readLine();
        FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("G:/java orig/csv1/" + "111.CSV" ); // nombre fichero 
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fichero); // variable de impresion
 
  
         while (null!=line) {
pw.println( "hola");
               
            String [] fields = line.split(SEPARATOR);
            String t1= fields[0];
            String pin_mod = t1.substring(0,4)+" "+t1.substring(4,8)+" "+t1.substring(8,12)+" "+t1.substring(12,16) ;        
            String t2= fields[1];
            String t4= fields[4];
            String  a  = t4.substring(0,4);
            String  m  = t4.substring(4,6);
            String  d  = t4.substring(6,8);
            System.out.println( pin_mod+ ";"+ t2+ ";"+ d + "/"+ m +"/"+ a );
//            System.out.println("t2  " +  t2);
//            System.out.println(  d + "/"+ m +"/"+ a);  
 pw.println( pin_mod+ ";"+ t2+ ";"+ d + "/"+ m +"/"+ a );
            line = br.readLine();
           
         
                            }
             pw.close();
         } catch (Exception e) { 
         
          } finally {
            if (null!=br) {
            br.close();
             
                    }
}  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `FileWriter` or `PrintWriter`? You define them but do not use them..

Comment: Yes,  I have tried to use them, without success

Comment: What did not work the way you expected?

Comment: [You're hiding errors](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)